# MongoDB: query against value in nested array?

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have documents with such kind of schema:

```
{
   ...
  "coverages" : [
    [
      "GB",
      "WC1"
    ],
    [
      "GB",
      "SE2"
    ],
    ...
  ]
}
```

I want to find all documents where 'coverages' contains an array second element of which starts with 'WC', i.e. coverages matches with ['GB', /^WC/].

Is there any way to do it with standard mongodb query language?

I guess it could be easily done with custom JavaScript function, but docs says it's much slower...

Thanks!

P.S.  I'd like to avoid changing the schema.

update: there is relates bug/misfeture in Mongo: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1264

Comment: Are you aware that the coverages key contains a list of lists? Just want to make sure you are doing that on purpose.

Comment: My bad, I was lazy and didn't mentioned that `coverages` is long list of pairs =\

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess this should work:

```
db.mycollection.find({"coverages": {"$elemMatch": {"2": /^WC/}}})
```

Comment: Just noticed that you have given "coverages" as an array of arrays. Is that a typo or is that how it is? If that is how your schema is defined, then change query to "coverages.0.1"

Comment: Yes, actually it's long array of arrays (pairs). And I want to find out if it's possible to query it without changing the schema, that's what this question is about :)

Comment: I've edited the code based on the edited example you have added

Comment: what "2" means in the query? Is it interpreted as position in array?

Answer (score 0):

`db.collection.find({ "coverages.0.1": /^WC/ })` should do the trick. It is saying, match documents where the second element of the first array in the key coverages starts with WC.

However, this is a bad schema if you are trying to associate GB (the first item in the array) with the second item in the array.

This is a natural case for the document/object/dictionary which maps keys to values.

Make it like this:

```
{
  "coverages" : { "GB": "WC1" }
}
```

Now your query much more naturally matches your logic: `db.collection.find({ "coverages.gb": /^WC/ })`

Comment: I've edited example: coverages contains much more than one element, so I guess your approach woudn't work :( I believe natural mongo schema for this case should look like "coverages": [{"country": "GB", "region": "WC1"}, ...].